# sendmail: how to add X-RBL-Warning

Tags: sendmail

I am running sendmail on CentOS.
I am interested if anyone knows how to add a X-RBL-Warning for incoming messages (without rejecting the mail).  I just want to add the X-RBL-Warning header so that our downstream filters can work with it.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using MIMEDefang (both with SpamAssassin and not).